# How to add bootstrap to empty asp.net core 2 template app?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, razor-pages

In an empty (template) asp.net core 2 app, after adding a Bootstrap package to the project, what else is needed to access Bootstrap?

I can see the Bootstrap NuGet under the NuGet node under dependencies. But none of the Bootstrap files in are `wwwroot`.

I've added one razor page with a button. However, it displays a normal looking button. Bootstrap isn't being used:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Bower to install the files (see [Manage client-side packages with Bower in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bower) for more info).

First add `bower.json` and `.bowerrc` files to your project root folder.

`bower.json` contents:

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "jquery": "3.2.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "3.2.1"
  }
}
```

`.bowerrc` contents

```
{
  "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}
```

Then from the Bower folder under Dependencies you can select Restore Packages and the files will be downloaded.

[image: Bower restore]

[image: wwwroot]

You can then reference bootstrap in a _Layout.cshtml file with both a relative link for development and a CDN link when published.

```
<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
```

And in `Startup.cs` add UseStaticFiles to enable the web server to return the CSS and JS files.

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
    ...
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    ...
}
```

Comment: When you right click on the solution to Manage Bower Packages and add Bootstrap, the output says it is adding bower.json. But I don't see it in the solution. What happened?

Comment: Also, when I add .bowerrc (text file), it goes under bower.json. Is that the way it is supposed to be? I can't disconnect them.

Comment: I have the files installed now but Bootstrap is not working. From this reference `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" >`, the browser displays this error in the console: `css ignored due to mime type mismatch`. If I replace it with the CDN reference, it works. Any idea what is wrong? In Chrome, there's no error but I get the same visual output (no bootstrap).

Comment: Didn't have the `app.UseStaticFiles()` middleware. Now everything is working.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include that. Glad its working now

Comment: newly created projects with the MVC template won't have any bower files, but rather a bundleconfig file. Is there a way to add these front-end support to an empty project without using bower?

Answer (score 0):

The files are not in the js folder. Try the following locations for the files:

```
<link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```